# How to make JButton know on which panel it has been clicked on?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to simulate a car renting system on a GUI.
Since I'm not very experienced with Swing components I decided to create a car list using GridBagLayout.

Each row has different panels each having different rental prices and car names.

[CarList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16gmM.png)

The "Details" button is shared through all the panels in the list. I'm looking for a way in which "Details" gets the title and price text from the panel were it was pressed, then saves them inside variables.

so far whenever I press it, it only saves and sends the text from the last panel in the list even if I pressed the first button in the list.

[CarDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UP6R.png)

This is the button's Event:

```java
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("details");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Car, price;
        Car = Name.getText();
        price = Price.getText();
        Main.add(new CarD(Car,price), "2");
        cl.show(Main, "2");
        add.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Following camickr's example, all that was left was to get the labels from the parent Panel using the location where they are placed within it.

```
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Details");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String Car, price;
                    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    JPanel panel = (JPanel)button.getParent();
                    JLabel N = (JLabel)panel.getComponentAt(202, 62);
                    JLabel P = (JLabel)panel.getComponentAt(202, 24);

                    Car = N.getText();
                    price = P.getText();
                    Main.add(new CarD(Car,price), "2");
                    cl.show(Main, "2");
                    add.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I see that you have three instances of details, so details is actually not shared. You could easily having it linked to other details from the same row (let's say the carid) which can then be used in the click event

Comment: But please post your code first, as your example should be minimal and reproducible

Comment: Post actual code in the forum, not an image of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ActionListener of your "Details" button you can get the button from the ActionEvent and the panel from the button:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
JPanel panel = (JPanel)button.getParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

In ActionListener try this :

```
    public void actionListener(ActionEvent evt)
    {
       if(evt.getSource()==b1)  // b1 is button variable
       {    
         //code
         // this will run if you click on b1 button
       }
       if(evt.getSource()==b2)  // b2 is another button variable
       {    
           //code
           // this will run if you click on b2 button
       }
    }
```